# Camera does not change FPS openCV JavaCameraView

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-camera, frame-rate

Using Android Camera(1) I am trying to change to a specific FPS rate, therefore I read out the available FPS ranges that the device's camera supports and try to pick a range that should be displayed in the preview.
OpenCV provides the tool FPSMeter which prints out the current FPS rate of the preview. No matter which FPS rate I am using, the FPS meter is still between 25 und 30 FPS.
By debugging I inspected the current camera parameters and the fps rate is the same I declared in my code.
The following code snippet should set the fps rate to min 20 max 20:

```
    List<int[]> fps = params.getSupportedPreviewFpsRange();
    if(fps != null)
    {
          params.setPreviewFpsRange(fps.get(3)[0],fps.get(3)[1]);
           Log.d(TAG, "Set preview FPS = " + fps.get(3)[0] + " " + fps.get(3)[1] );
    }
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
```